# I washed the dishes clean

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

Firstly, is "I washed the dishes clean." a grammatically correct sentence?

If it is right, I have a question about it: in this sentence, is "clean" an adverb or an adjective?

I think that "I cleanly washed the dishes." is a correct sentence and I also think "I washed the dishes cleanly" is a correct sentence, using "cleanly" as an adverb.

But I wonder whether "I washed the dishes clean" is a correct sentence or not.

Comment: *"I washed the dishes cleanly"* and *"I washed the dishes clean"* mean two different things.

Comment: I painted the wall red.

Comment: It seems to be grammatically correct ("clean" is an adjective here), but it sounds odd to me. People normally just say "I washed the dishes."

Comment: @sumelic For people with my limited dish-washing skill, "clean" might add relevant information.  (I should probably stick to redly painting walls.)

Comment: The dog licked the plate clean, after which you washed the plate really clean.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more natural example will illustrate the syntax.  Consider the preparation for painting a wall:

> [1] I scraped the wall **bare**.
>   [2] I **barely** scraped the wall.

In [1], *bare* is an adjectival complement describing the condition of the wall.  When I'm done, I end up with a *bare* wall. In [2], *barely* is an adverb telling us the manner in which I did the job, which is to say hardly at all. (Which, ironically, also describes how I clean dishes.)

Comment: Bare and barely don't have the same semantic relationship as clean and cleanly.  I cleanly handled the dishes, so they were clean.  I barely handled the dishes, so they were bare (??)   Also, you mean coincidentally, not ironically.

Comment: @StevenLittman Two lessons, here.  The first is that the answer illustrates syntax, not semantics -- the difference between an adverbial and an adjectival use of words.  Secondly, please don't tell me what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *[resultative construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative)*. You can look at the Wikipedia page or a detailed reference grammar for more details.

> In linguistics, a resultative is a form that expresses that something
> or someone has undergone a change in state as the result of the
> completion of an event. Resultatives appear as predicates of
> sentences, and are generally composed of a verb (denoting the event) a
> postverbal noun phrase (denoting the entity that has undergone a
> change) and a so-called resultative phrase (denoting the state
> achieved as the result of the action named by the verb) which may
> be represented by an adjective, a prepositional phrase, or a particle,
> among others.
>
> For example, in the English sentence The man wiped
> the table clean, the adjective clean denotes the state achieved by the
> table as a result of the event described as the man wiped.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It's also a link-only answer.

Comment: @Catija grammatically incorrect sentence templates are not named, so providing the name of the template proves that it is widely considered correct.

Comment: @jlovegren I think you need to do a bit more. Links are nice, but an answer should stand on its own. As it is, it would make a nice comment.

Comment: @jlovegren Hello, jlovegren. I copied and pasted the essential part of the link. Link-only answer is discouraged on ELU as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. I upvote your valid answer.